# Angular 2/4 : Assign array value from promise function in service layer to a variable in component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am calling post function in service layer using Promise which returns me a JSONArray . I am able to fetch it in components layer but unable to assign to a variable .

**What i tried is :**

```
config;


ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getTemplateData(this.templateId).then(result => this.config = result)
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

:: result is printing jsonArray properly
```

***I get following error in console.***

```
AppComponent.html:34 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at DynamicFormComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/dynamic-form/containers/dynamic-form/dynamic-form.component.ts.DynamicFormComponent.createGroup (dynamic-form.component.ts:24)
    at DynamicFormComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/dynamic-form/containers/dynamic-form/dynamic-form.component.ts.DynamicFormComponent.ngOnInit (dynamic-form.component.ts:19)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10843)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12341)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12284)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13141)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13082)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:34)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13067)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12251)
```

***What I'm expecting is :***

```
config = [
    {
      "type": "input",
      "label": "Full name",
      "name": "name",
      "placeholder": "Enter your name"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "label": "Favourite food",
      "name": "food",
      "options": ["Pizza", "Hot Dogs", "Knakworstje", "Coffee"],
      "placeholder": "Select an option"
    },
    {
      "label": "Submit",
      "name": "submit",
      "type": "button"
    },
  ];
```

**Following is my .html logic :-**

```
  <div class="app">
            <dynamic-form [config]="config">
            </dynamic-form>
  </div>
```

**My Service Layer** :

getTemplateData(data:any): Promise {

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http
        .post(this.templateDataUrl, data, options)
    .toPromise()
    .then(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

 private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
}
```

Comment: The error is in your html for that component, can you please add it to the question. `AppComponent.html:34`

Comment: Please console log result and show it.

Comment: I have included my html and service layer content in the question

Comment: You have an error on your `app.component.ts`. Please include the code that contains the `forEach`

Comment: that error comes to me when i assign my result jsonArray to config as shared in the above code

Answer (score 0):

Please share the complete code of dynamic-form.component. it will be easy to trace the issue.

```
DynamicFormComponent.createGroup (dynamic-form.component.ts:24)
```

on the above line, config is undefined that's why it's throwing an error
    u should call a `creatGroup()` method like this

```
 this.dataService.getTemplateData(this.templateId).then(result => {
    this.config = result;
    this.creatGroup()
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Refer the added html and service layer in my question i  just edited . If you need any other file code , ill share . thank you

Comment: Can you please share the code for dynamic-form.component.ts anf dynamic-form.component.html file?

Comment: Well , Issue solved . I properly initialised "config" and now i am able to assign. Thanks for help everybody

Answer (score 0):

Initialising config variable properly, I was able to assign data to the parameter

```
config: any[] = [];
```